# Samba Share on Pi – Windows & Linux can write but not applications (Sublime, Codeblocks)

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, shared-folders

### Context (irrelevant):

I was looking around the net and stack for this particular issue but couldn't find an answer. Some answers even suggested enabling guest_ok which is in my honest opinion a massive security flaw, even in a home network, although I could be wrong, the chances tend to the latter :)

### 1. Situation

**I had a pi(hole) 3 laying around and wanted to enable a common place for all my everyday files.** Files that I read & edit on a regular basis like code, scripts or even simple notes / txt.

I followed a guide with my linux knowledge and ended up with a functional samba share on the pi's inserted usb stick, accessible from everywhere in my LAN.

### 2. Problem

The problem is that applications like sublime or codeblocks are unable to create files. I can still move files in and out with the regular file explorer/thunar though editing existing files in sublime works but I have to enter the password every. single. time. (so if you press Ctlr+S 20x, that's 20 times entering the same password). Starting applications with sudo results in "Save as" being unable to display the samba share though this was more of an experiment since you wouldn't run Sublime etc... as root on a regular user anyway.

### 3. Samba smb config:

```
[NetworkDrive]
path = /network
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
valid users = pi
public = no
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

EDIT: Even setting guest and public to yes, results in the beforementioned no permission error in sublime etc...

As you can see, I login with the pi user's cred, which seems to work fine, on other platforms since I don't wish to create another extra user and the hassle of permissions etc..., if the pi user exists and somewhat works, why not.

### 4. Conclusion

How can I make it so that applications such as text editors and IDEs have the permission to create, edit and read on the Share just like the explorer? Also the request for password for each Cntrl+S has to stop as well :(

Comment: I don't see any OS or release mentioned; so providing that detail allows us to know your software stack & thus how to help you. Is your system a Ubuntu Core? (ie. *snap* only system) or what OS & release are you using?

Comment: It may be a snap related problem. Did you try to test with non-snap applications?

Comment: Client:Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS though I tried it on Debian as well.
Pi: The raspian debian minimal version

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: Even setting guest and public to yes, results in the beforementioned no permission error in sublime etc...
>
>
> If you haven't already, make sure to run `sudo service smbd restart` when you are finished with any changes.
>
> ANYWAY,
>
>
> You should try out `force user = pi` in your CONFIG file. This should require no authentication on your end when saving files if I recall correctly. As for security flaws,  as long as nobody has the server's local IP address (since I don't think you'll be port forwarding SAMBA), you should be fine. `public = no` handles this pretty well.

Well, ignore this now.

I installed Samba, and the main cause for "Permission denied" errors was because the shared folder was not owned by the logged-in user trying to edit it. `sudo chown pi /network` in your case should work. Reload the service with `sudo service smbd restart`, and things should work.

Authenticating all saves to your Raspberry Pi should be fixed with this too.

Comment: Thanks. the service command doesnt work, I get a "samba.service not found" error.
systemctl start smb.service retrieves me a smb.service not found as well. What is going on.

Comment: Sorry, many apologies. It's actually `sudo service smbd restart`. Try that instead.

Comment: I added force user = pi and still receive no permission errors in editors etc... I think I am just going to abandon the idea of authentication entirely

Comment: Okay so I removed the valid users and force user lines and set guest ok to yes. Restarted with the command you gave and still receive no permission errors.

Samba config: [NetworkDrive]
path = /network
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
public = no
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777

<- Of course formated since Stack won't permit new lines & spaces in comments.

Comment: If so, I'll run some tests myself.

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium This might just be a permissions problem because the network directory you made isn't owned by the `pi` user.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I append the solution to the problem. Sadly this has no decisive solution.
I can simply give you the config and tell you what I did which solved my issue:

```
[Nameofyourshare]
path = /path/to/your/share
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
force user = pi
public = no
```

*<---Removed guest ok and the default seems to be yes I dont know.*

```
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

I believe the real solution to my specific case is to set the vers in the cifs mount command specifically to 1.0, which weirdly enough fixed connection/access/Permission denied errors on my Phone (test, 1.0 worked, 2.0 even if forced in smb conf didnt work).

Though the unmount could also have fixed this issue. I dont know. If you have the same issue,  here's what I would tell you, test if your phone can connect with either `SMB protocol v1 or v2.` If only v1 works without authentication or connection/permission issues then use the command: `sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,username=pi //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/NetworkDrive/ /mnt/` <--- The 'x' represent the ip of the share/device, username the one from force user from .conf and /mnt where to be mounted.

As for @Nirbodha, I thank you for helping and would've upvoted your reply if I had >= 15 rep. Sadly I can't pick your reply as the definitive solution, though it's part of the solution. I truely think the protocol version (&remounting maybe) was the issue.